# MouseArea prevents editing

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: myWindow2
    title: qsTr("test window")
    x: 500
    y: 200
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    TextEdit
    {
        id: tEdit

        anchors.fill: parent

        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            cursorShape: Qt.IBeamCursor
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow the 'MouseArea' prevents the 'tEdit' to work. It does change the shape of the cursor thou. How can I have the shape changed and the 'tEdit' working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting [`acceptedButtons`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#acceptedButtons-prop) to `Qt.NoButton` seems to work:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: myWindow2
    x: 500
    y: 200
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    TextEdit {
        id: tEdit
        anchors.fill: parent

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            cursorShape: Qt.IBeamCursor
            acceptedButtons: Qt.NoButton
        }
    }
}
```

Note that text selection via mouse still works, you just have to set it to true:

```
selectByMouse: true
```